# How do I use php functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Situation:
I'm building a Wordpress Site. Menu becomes 'fixed' to the top of the page when scrolling down the page (http://deerfielddesigns.com.mlseo.net/). When i am logged into wordpress, the dashboard admin bar cover the menu. I wanted to create a different class for the menu when I am logged in as opposed to when I am logged out.

Code:

```
    if ( direction === 'down' ) {

        $('#main-header').addClass( 'et-fixed-header' );
    } else {
        $('#main-header').removeClass( 'et-fixed-header' );
    }
```

I wanted to insert an "if ( is_user_logged_in() )" statement in there to change the class output but I don't really understand too much about javascript and if it plays nice with php. Does anyone have any insight as to what i need to do to make this work? Thanks all!

Comment: You can't call a PHP function from Javascript. You'd need an AJAX call to a PHP script to do that.

Comment: He doesn't really want to call a PHP function, he just poorly stated the question. What he wants is to use jQuery to manipulate classes if user is logged in (see his code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is not an AJAX driven login system, simply open your `header.php` file and perform the following

```
$the_class = is_user_logged_in() ? 'logged-in-class' : 'logged-out-class';
```

Then find your `main-header` and do what's required.

```
<header id="main-header" class="<?php echo $the_class;">
```

If it is an ajax driven login system, you'll need to understand how to work with wordpress' `add_action`, but that is an answer for an entirely different question.

Answer (score 0):

Make an ajax request to the required php function whenever required. You may use ajax features of various JS libraries like jQuery, YUI etc. to do so.

Comment: This is true in general, but if you read his question you'll see that he's trying to tell if the user is logged in inside a scroll event.  Sending out ajax requests every time the user scrolls is a bad idea...

Comment: Agreed; but why should one actually check if a user is logged in inside a scroll event? That is insane right?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language (which quite likely is generating Javascript).
Javascript is in the browser.

The short answer is "You can't easily call PHP from JS".

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to identify from you javascript if a user is logged in is to populate a javascript variable with their status.  In your theme's header.php, add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var is_logged_in = <?php echo json_encode(is_user_logged_in()) ?>;
</script>
```

Then, in your javascript elsewhere, you can use:

```
if (is_logged_in) {
   //....
}
```

Comment: I attempted this but for some reason my 'else' statements weren't working when I wanted to add a class if the user was not logged in. Probably some error on my end, but I got it working using Ohgodwhy's solution. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you write inline javascript in your php files you can do this:

```
<?php  // some php code ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
    // Place some javascript here
<?php } else { ?>
    // Place some javascript here
<?php ?>

</script>

<?php  // some php code ?>
```